# Find duplicate xml documents in a directory depends upon the tag element using python script

Tags: python-2.7

I have a multiple xml documents in a directory. I need to parse the xml documents and have to find the duplicate documents by comparin the tag element from one document into another

Example:

```
<xml>
 <name>
   <firstname>xxx</firstname>
   <lastname>yyy</lastname>
 </name>
</xml>
```

Like this, all the files having same tags and different or same value. By using the firstname, i have to find out the duplicate xml document using python script.